# pgSQL : insert date format (leading zeros)?

Tags: php, sql, forms, postgresql

I want to insert a date into my pg database, but I haven't got a clue what the correct format is and the pg help isn't really helping.

I have my date from form in d-m-yyyy format. So leading zeros are omitted.

How can I insert this correctly, is there a function to add leading zeros (either pg or php) ?

Comment: Just for completeness: The relevant standard is [ISO 8601 *Data elements and interchange formats -- Information interchange -- Representation of dates and times*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8601).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TheTable (the_date) VALUES ('yyyy-mm-dd')
```

is the correct order in SQL

```
$psql_str = date('yyyy-mm-dd', date_parse_from_format('d-m-yyyy', $date_str));
```

converts your `$date_str` to the expcted format.

Answer (score 6):

Check [`to_date(text, text)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) function ([Table 9-21](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) contains all supported patterns):

```
SELECT to_date('1-9-2011', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
  to_date   
------------
 2011-09-01
(1 row)
```

As you see leading zeros are properly added in output date.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is insert the date in an unambiguous format, since that's guaranteed to always work, regardless of any settings that the server may have. The recommended format is YYYY-MM-DD. You can change your date to that format with this function:

```
function convertDate($old) {
    $date = explode('-', $old);
    if (strlen($date[0]) == 1)
        $date[0] = '0' . $date[0];
    if (strlen($date[1]) == 1)
        $date[1] = '0' . $date[1];
    $new = date[2] . '-' . $date[1] . '-' . $date[0];
    return $new;
}
```

Other data formats are also possible, but they are less recommended, since they rely on settings that may vary from one server to another. For more information, check out [the relevant section of the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you verify that DateStyle is set to DMY (or, better, "ISO,DMY"), then you don't have to do *anything*:

```
postgres=# create table test_table (date_field date);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# show DateStyle;
 DateStyle 
-----------
 ISO, MDY
(1 row)

postgres=# set DateStyle='ISO, DMY';
SET

postgres=# insert into test_table (date_field) values ('2-4-2011');
INSERT 0 1

postgres=# select * from test_table;
 date_field 
------------
 2011-04-02
(1 row)
```